# To disable all radio buttons if anyone of them is clicked in angularjs ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

what i am trying to do here is, i have an ng-repeat in a form and if i click anyone of those input buttons corresponding all buttons get disabled

```
<div ng-repeat="question in sinSurCtrl.singleSurvey" ng-show="!$first">
        <hr>
            <p>Q. {{question.questionText}}</p>
            <form >
                <div ng-repeat=" option in question.questionOptions track by $index">   
                    <label>
                        <input name="options" type="radio" value="$index" ng-click="sinSurCtrl.questionId=question.questionId; sinSurCtrl.answer=$index+1; sinSurCtrl.createAnswer()" onclick="this.disabled = true">
                        <span> {{option}} {{$index+1}} {{question.questionId}} </span>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
```

here is the view-
[image: this is how code will look after execution]

as you can see if i select anyone of those option it is getting disabled but what i am trying to do is if i attempt anyone option then options corresponding to the same question get disabled.
for example-
in Q3. which is a better orator ?
if i choose option (a) then it get selected and after that automatically bot options (a) and (b) get disabled.

Note- please try to keep solution completely in angularjs or if you want use affordable amount of javascript other then that please avoid using external libraries like jQuery(i know nobody in his senses will handle trouble of using jQuery and angular together but for the sake of example i have included its name)

[image: i have no tracking function in my controller]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Proposed solution with some suggested refactoring...**

First change the `ng-click` directive to point to a new `onOptionButtonClicked` function on `sinSurCtrl` which takes in the two parameters `question` and `index` (which it needs to carry out it's work):

```
<div ng-repeat="question in sinSurCtrl.singleSurvey" ng-show="!$first">
  <hr>
  <p>Q. {{question.questionText}}</p>
  <form>
    <div ng-repeat="option in question.questionOptions track by $index">   
      <label>
        <input 
          name="options" 
          type="radio" 
          value="$index"
          ng-click="onOptionButtonClicked(question, $index)"
          ng-disabled="question.disabled">
        <span> {{option}} {{$index+1}} {{question.questionId}} </span>
      </label>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Also take note of the newly added `ng-disabled="question.disabled"` directive. This is part of the mechanism that will enable/disable the question's controls.

Now move the variable assignments to the new `onOptionButtonClicked` function. The controller is generally a better place (than the view) for variable assignments, especially if there are several of them on the same directive.

```
sinSurCtrl.onOptionButtonClicked = onOptionButtonClicked;

function onOptionButtonClicked(question, index){
  sinSurCtrl.questionId=question.questionId; 
  sinSurCtrl.answer=index; 
  sinSurCtrl.createAnswer();
  question.disabled = true; // <--- This is what disables the option buttons
}
```

This is where an answered `question` object gets it's `disabled` property set to `true`. This in combination with the `ng-disabled` directive mentioned previously is what disables the option buttons.

Comment: with some minor modification your answer fitted perfectly on what i was trying to accomplish.

Comment: @samartajShaikh Pleased it helped. What else did you change? I'll update the answer to reflect the changes.

Comment: no nothing with your answer but in my function invocations and services, which i edited as per your answer, thanks for the gesture.

Answer (score 0):

On your controller, create a function that checks if a given questionId has been answered and return truthy if it has. Call that function in `ng-disabled` in the input tag:

```
<input type="radio" ng-disabled="sinSurCtrl.questionHasAnswer(question.questionId)" ... />
```

Comment: as soon as a radio button is clicked a $http POST request is initiated which directly sends the user input to a server, hence i am not keeping any kind of record thus i can't make that kind of function.

Comment: But databinding is the angular way of doing it. You need data to bind to. Even if it's a simple array of answered question IDs on the controller.

Comment: Another idea: In your on-click, after calling `createAnswer()` set a flag on the question object. `question.answered = true` and bind your ng-disabled to it.

Comment: yes, you are right, i am maintaining an array of responses but directly on the server side, the array has two possible values either 1 or 2 and if any question has 4 options then array variables can range from 1 to 4 and on the server side on counting them as how many of which option. It is not a sample code of a quiz application, it's a sample code of a survey application.

Comment: as you can see in edit i have no record of question either everything is maintained by ui-router application

Comment: although singleSurvey is an array of objects which has 4 objects 1st is for question heading and instructions and other three are survey questions with an array of options and responses, and i am only fetching them and displaying them, i have no data whatsoever on my machine.